# How do I set a default Chrome Person (user) to open URLs as?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, default-browser

When I click on a URL (e.g. a URL in output console in bash), it opens using Chrome. Since I have multiple Persons (or users) on Chrome, it seemed to always open using the person with most recently seen window.

Is it possible to make a particular person the default to open URLs like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ubuntu Unity Desktop** uses **`*.desktop`** files set the default programs for file types. In order to achieve what you desire you can create a custom `*.desktop` file for google-chrome just for your user.

This will take a couple of steps:

---

### 1. Verify Default Program

Verify that `google-chrome.desktop` is your default program for opening links:

In Terminal enter: `cat ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`.

> Output should be something like this:
>
> > `[Default Applications]
> >     text/html=google-chrome.desktop
> >     x-scheme-handler/http=google-chrome.desktop
> >     x-scheme-handler/https=google-chrome.desktop
> >     x-scheme-handler/about=google-chrome.desktop
> >     x-scheme-handler/unknown=google-chrome.desktop
> >     x-scheme-handler/mailto=google-chrome.desktop
> >     text/x-c++src=gedit.desktop`
> >
> > `[Added Associations]
> >     text/x-c++src=gedit.desktop;`

If like in the example `google-chrome.desktop` is handling the web links then proceed as described. If not you need to set the default program first.

---

### 2. Create Custom *.desktop File

Creating a custom `google-chrome.desktop` file at `~/.local/share/applications/` based on the original `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file.

In Terminal enter:

> `cp /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/`

- Doing this you will only change the settings for your user and not all users in the machine.
- If a `*.desktop` file name from `/usr/share/applications/` is duplicated at `~/.local/share/applications/` then the local one takes priority.

---

### 3. Edit new *.desktop file

This file will contain many lines for names of options in different languages. We will need to edit all lines starting with `Exec=`.

Example from my computer at: `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`

> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --incognito

In the new file at `~/.local/share/applications/` change these lines by adding the option `--profile-directory=Default`.

> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Default %U
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Default
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Default --incognito

This will make it so every time you open a link it will be opened by the **Default** user.

---

## Different User

The option `--profile-directory=` can be set to the name of anyone folder at `~/.config/google-chrome/` that holds user configuration. Examples:

- Default
- Profile 1
- Profile 2
- etc...

Example:

> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Profile\ 1 %U
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Profile\ 1
>
> Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Profile\ 1 --incognito

Observe the *backslash*`\` in `Profile\ 1` to indicate the folder name includes a space.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed information. This works for me!
One question, how do I know which user name corresponds to "Default", "Profile 1" and so on?

Comment: I can only  recommend that you press `Alt`+`F2` and enter the command: `google-chrome-stable --profile-directory=Profile\ X`. The `X` being anyone of the values under `~/.config/google-chrome/`. Trial and error is the quickest option I can find.